# Lodash _.chain with flatten to find matching value array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to find matching object from my multidimensional array with help of [lodash](/questions/tagged/lodash) library. I am using combination of `_.chain` along with flatten to go one level deeper.

Don't know what approach I should use. Can anyone please review and help me out to get expected result?

[JSFIDDLE Lin](https://jsfiddle.net/upvd238v/1/)

```
var team = _.chain(data).flatten("divisionTeams").find({"id": 3222}).value();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first use `map()` to return `divisionTeams` and then flatten and find.

```js
var data = [{"divisionName":"5th Grade - Green","divisionTeams":[{"id":3222,"name":"Columbia Ravens 5th","coach":"John Miller"},{"id":4299,"name":"D1 Spartans","coach":"Jacob Silverman"},{"id":3220,"name":"HC Elite OMalley 5th","coach":"Eddie OMalley"},{"id":3277,"name":"MD 3D 5th","coach":"Marty Libinski"},{"id":3275,"name":"Severn Elite Gold","coach":"Darryl Adams"},{"id":3224,"name":"Team Dedication 5th","coach":"Don Carpenter"}]},{"divisionName":"5th Grade - White","divisionTeams":[{"id":3225,"name":"CBSA Hoyas 5th Grade","coach":"Terrance Taylor"},{"id":3276,"name":"HC Elite 4th Tookes","coach":"Anthony Tookes"},{"id":3221,"name":"HC Elite Knisley 5th","coach":"Jordan Knisley"},{"id":3226,"name":"Randelstown Runnin Rebels 5th","coach":"Eric Levi"},{"id":3223,"name":"Up n Coming Clippers 5th","coach":"Brian Jackson"}]}]

var team = _.chain(data)
 .map(e => e.divisionTeams)
 .flatten()
 .find({ "id": 3222})
 .value();

console.log(JSON.stringify(team));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @nenad-vracar for your quick help. It worked like a super shot. :-)